# how to scan lines of JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, textarea

As the title says, I want to  scan a textArea. Is it possible to scan both numbers and strings?
One more thing, I use `setBounds` for the position of the textArea, but it doesn't work.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextArea {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JTextArea area = new JTextArea(4, 10);

public TextArea() {

    area.setBounds(110, 250, 40, 40); //doesn't work

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(area);
    frame.setTitle("Area");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(900, 580);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TextArea();
}
}
```

Comment: don't use `setBounds` rely that work to the Layout Manager you implicity are using (FlowLayout). What you mean by scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the text inside the textarea just by doing

```
String contents = area.getText();
```

Once you have the String you can use any string processing you like (for example `split("\n")` to split it into lines) on it.

Comment: i know, exists a faster way to do this?for example when i write a line in textarea, i can split this without get the entire text?

Comment: for the position of the area,how i can fix it? setbounds doesnt works

Comment: @CiMat to position the area you need to set up the layout manager of the panel it is on and use the appropriate layout constraints...or use an IDE that will let you graphically design the pannels. (Netbeans has that feature for example).

Answer (score 3):

You can implement  [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) and act as an observer of the document to listen for example when the text is inserted/removed. Take a look in how to do it in [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Comment: for the position of the area,how i can fix it? setbounds doesnt works

Comment: Learn about [How to use Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). Frame defaults is BorderLayout then you add to the center a panel this will get all screen, then jpanel default layout manager is `FlowLayout` you add a JTextArea (I recommend you to use a JScrollPane with JTextArea) this will get in the center.